# how to map interface in nhibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have interface `IArticle` which should be implement by all articles. `ArticleBase` abtract class defines common properties for every article and `ArticleA`, `ArticleB` further defines specific propertis of those articles. This situation is described more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308220/entity-interface-relationship-how-to-map).

To accomplish situation where every image can have any type of article and since every article implements `IArticle` I decided to use IArticle type of data inside Image class.

Since I'm having hard time figuring out how to map those relationships with interface, I tried to map IArticle using nhibernate mapping by code and all other classes which implements IArticle to map using SubclassMapping  with DiscriminatorValue

```
public class ArticleAMap : SubclassMapping<ArticleA>
{
   public ArticleAMap()
   {
      DiscriminatorValue("ArticleA");
      ... mapping other ArticleA specific properties ...
   }
}

public class IArticleMap : ClassMapping<IArticle>
{
   public IArticleMap()
   {
      Property(x => x.Category, m =>
      {
         m.NotNullable(true);
      });
      ....
   }
}
```

Since my `IArticle` doesn’t have access to Entity class which is responsible for creating unique identifier I cannot map Id. On the other hand I can use `ArticleBase` which implements `Entity.cs` and `IArticle` but I then I will lose access to `IArticle` which can be used in `DI`.

So question is: Which is the best way to map interface in nhibernate using mapping by code?

Comment: I don't understand your issue (it is Monday Morning so apologies if I've overlooked something) - surely as `ArticleBase : IArticle` you don't have any problems with DI? Just map `ArticleBase` and sub-class-map off that. Besides you can always DI with the abstract class.

Comment: so basically, you're saying that I should change IArticle association to ArticleBase and I still be in position to use IArticle in DI implementation? If so, thanks, post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ArticleBase` implements `IArticle` and all your `*Article`s inherit from `ArticleBase` you shouldn't have any problem dependency injection wise with mapping your `ArticleBase` as the base class:

```
public class ArticleBaseMap : ClassMapping<ArticleBase>
{
    public ArticleBaseMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.Category, m =>
        {
            m.NotNullable(true);
        });
        // ...
    }
}
```